# Why is my computer sometimes assigned two internal IP addresses?

Tags: linux, debian, ip, hostname

I run Debian 10 and sometimes when I start the computer the output of `hostname -I` has three entries:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.0.13 192.168.0.2 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8
```

Sometimes it has one less:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.0.2 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8
```

I can't understand where 192.168.0.13 comes from. Here is the content of my hosts file:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       desktop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**Edit:**

When only 192.168.0.2 shows up the output of `ip address` is

```
$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:9a:20:f8:dc:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s10
       valid_lft 3361sec preferred_lft 3361sec
    inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 2006054647sec preferred_lft 2006054647sec
    inet6 fe80::d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:84:0d:f3:85:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**Edit 2021-06-16:**

When 192.168.0.13 and 192.168.0.2 show up the output of `ip address` is

```
$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:9a:20:f8:dc:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.13/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s10
       valid_lft 2290sec preferred_lft 2290sec
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary dynamic enp0s10
       valid_lft 2666sec preferred_lft 2666sec
    inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 2006054625sec preferred_lft 2006054625sec
    inet6 fe80::d69a:20ff:fef8:dca8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:84:0d:f3:85:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: This could happen if you are plugged in via ethernet AND you are connected with your wifi.  For more info, can you give us the output of `ip address` in both cases?

Comment: @Stewart Thanks for the input. I can see in the network connection manager *wicd* that I'm not connected through WIFI, only ethernet. I have updated the question with the output from `ip address` when 192.168.0.13 doesn't show up.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Also look at `ip route`. `man ip ip-route`. The `default` route is where almost all IP packets go.

Comment: Your `wlan0` `MTU` is 1500, should be 1492, this should be set up by your WiFi's DHCP server, but `sudo ip set dev wlan0 mtu 1492` just in case. Avoid packet fragmentation!

Comment: @Stewart I have added the output from `ip address` when both address 192.168.0.13 and 192.168.0.2 show up. I cannot understand why 192.168.0.13 is also in use instead of just 192.168.0.2.

Comment: Seems more likely this has to do with DHCP server/client configuration than host configuration (Since it appears your IPs are not statically assigned).  Is the routing device connected to enp0s10 managed? If so, can you add DHCP configurations to your question?